# How to make an object move continuously diagonally in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, draw

I'm very new to pygame as well as python and making a 2D shooter where you can shoot a bullet when the mouse is pressed. The bullet should be drawn initially at the player and move diagonally following the gradient which is found by dividing the difference in y value of the player and the cursor by the difference in x value of the player and the cursor. Am I overcomplicating things?

relevant code for what I tried is shown below:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet(cursor_position)
```

```
def bullet(cursor_pos):
    bullet_velocity = 3
    bullet_x = player_x
    bullet_y = player_y
    cursor_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    travelDistance_x = cursor_pos[0] - bullet_x
    travelDistance_y = cursor_pos[1] - bullet_y
    gradient = travelDistance_y / travelDistance_x
    change = 1
    new_x = bullet_x + change
    new_y = gradient * new_x
    bullet_x = new_x
    bullet_y = new_y
    
    bullet = pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (bullet_x, bullet_y), 5)  # Draw the bullet
```

Note: This code will sometimes show a blue circle a small distance away from the player but it disappears after releasing click.